# How to wrap a sideways text in a column (tabular)

Tags: rotation, latex, tabular

Let's say we have a table

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\begin{sideways}A\end{sideways}&\begin{sideways}B\end{sideways}\\\  
a & b \\\  
\end{tabular}
```

How can I define the height of cells `A` and `B`, so that in case of `A` and `B` being a longer caption, the text will wrap-around the cell?
Putting `p{x pt}` in the tabular environment's table specs doesn't seem to do the trick..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippet creates a box that is 1/4 of an inch wide, and includes the letter a.

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{.25in} a. \end{minipage}
```

Anyway, increase the size to whatever is needed, and add better text.